# Set-theoretic definition of a matrix? (and related question)

Tags: matrices, set-theory

An ordered pair of numbers $(x,y)$ is usually defined in set theory as the set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, and analogously for triplets and so on.

What is the usual or most adopted set-theoretic definition (or definitions) of, say, a 2-by-3 matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x &y&z \\ a&b&c\end{pmatrix}$? Maybe there isn't one?

Related question: what is the set-theoretic difference between an ordered pair $(x,y)$ and a 1-by-2 row matrix $\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}$?

A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162576/455507), but I don't find the answer acceptable, since it appears to be only the poster's personal view and doesn't provide any references.

The three references given in the [wikipedia article on matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Definition) do not seem very helpful either: **Lang**'s *Algebra* defines a matrix as a "a doubly indexed family of elements
of [a commutative ring]". I don't know if this can be taken as a set-theoretic definition. After all Lang doesn't define what an "ordered pair" is from a set-theoretic point of view, nor what an "indexed family" is. This (great) text does not seem to be concerned with set-theoretic definitions.
**Fraleigh**'s *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* and **Nering**'s *Linear Algebra and
Matrix Theory* define a matrix as "a rectangular array" of numbers or scalars. OK, what's the set-theoretic definition of "rectangular array" then? (The texts don't say.)

Comment: A [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Definition) is a "double-index" finite sequence $\{ a_{11}, a_{12}, \ldots, a_{1n}, a_{21}, \ldots , a_{nm} \}$. Thus, e.g. a real-valued matrix is a function $f : \{1,\ldots, n \} \times \{ 1, \ldots, m \} \to \mathbb R$ where $f(i,j)= a_{ij}$

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: You have a link to Wikipedia provided by @MauroALLEGRANZA , and that has further references.  The point I would include is that what makes a matrix more than a simple rectangular array is the particular definition of addition and multiplication of matrices.  If you want a complete set-theoretic definition, then you will need to include these; nobody does that because it makes more sense to build on previous definitions.

Comment: @pglpm I would make the important distinction that a matrix is to be defined as a *family* of objects and not as a function. More specifically, given arbitrary finite sets $I$ and $J$ together with an arbitrary ring $A$, a matrix of type $(I, J)$ over $A$ is a family of elements of $A$ indexed by the cartesian product $I \times J$. More succinctly, a matrix of type $(I, J)$ over $A$ is simply an element of the cartesian product $A^{I \times J}$. The reason why matrices should *not* be defined as functions but as families is that fixing a codomain is not important *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @pglpm *(cont.)* and even more than that, it actually constitutes a hindrance. To give an example, one would like to be able to claim a square matrix of order say $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ is at the same time a square matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$, or more briefly put to assert the inclusion $\mathscr{M}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq \mathscr{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. With matrices defined as functions that is not possible (it would be an invalid claim), since a function with codomain $\mathbb{Z}$ can never be equal to one with codomain $\mathbb{Q}$ (for the simple reason that $\mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately the references given in the wikipedia article aren't very useful – see my edited question.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ thank you for the reasoned insights, they are very useful. So maybe there is no consensus on a set-theoretic definition?

Comment: @Henry I get your point. So the conclusion possibly is that there really isn't any "official" set-theoretic definition.

Comment: @pglpm I don't think it is so relevant whether there is an established consensus or not, since ultimately that which is correct, good and appropriate is not decided by consensus. My comment I hope presents adequate justification for why the definition of matrices as *families* is **the only** appropriate one. That ultimately any partaker of mathematics can choose a definition of his/her own personal preference, with that I have nothing to differ. However, out of the various options there is just one that makes the most sense for this topic.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Your argument would be more plausible if $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, but that is often not literally the case.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I agree that relevance of consensus in science is a matter of everyone's subjective view, of context, history, sociology, and so on. In this case I was simply curious whether there is any commonly used definition (as for ordered pairs, for example, which can also be given alternative definitions), or not :)

Comment: @Zhen Lin I understand what you refer to, but for utter consistency may I mention that I am part of a school which constructs $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ so that the set-theoretical inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ rigorously take place, not just as a mere *identification via canonical embedding*. Whether I might be the only disciple of this school I do not know, but it certainly is perfectly feasible to implement canonical constructions such that the inclusions $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ are rigorously satisfied.

Comment: @ZhenLin (*cont.*) And although this is not essential to the justifying argument I presented above I nevertheless was and am speaking from a position where those canonical inclusions (that you address) literally are set-theoretical inclusions.

Comment: What is "the official" way of storing a string in your computer's memory? Is it big endian or little endian? Is it ASCII or UTF-8 or UTF-12 or UTF-16? Maybe it's some other encoding? Is it a null-terminated sequence, or is it an object with more properties like its length and pointers to generic functions like substrings and so on?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you, "official" was an inappropriate term indeed. What I mean is a sort of standard or generally accepted definition. Just like "$\{x, \{x,y\}\}$" is the generally accepted definition of the ordered pair $(x,y)$, although alternative definitions are, or could be, given for it.

Comment: @Henry "what makes a matrix more than a simple rectangular array is the particular definition of addition and multiplication of matrices. If you want a complete set-theoretic definition, then you will need to include these" I strongly disagree with that claim. From a set-theoretic standpoint, the algebraic structure of matrices is not part of what they are (as set-theoretic objects); so there's no difference between arrays and matrices in this context. Think about how the natural numbers are standardly represented in set theory as finite ordinals and ordinal arithmetic is only defined *later*.

Comment: Put another way, what we want to do with Xs won't be literally part of the set-theoretic definition of Xs; rather, it will *motivate* certain definitions as those which make things more convenient to work with ultimately.

Comment: @pglpm: My point here is that ultimately set theory provides you with a framework in which you can encode mathematics. How exactly you do it is entirely up to you. Usually we formalise first things like ordered pairs, then functions, then we simply define matrices as certain elements of certain vector spaces, but it *very much* doesn't matter at the end. Let me also add that the "generally accepted definition" of an ordered pair is $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ and not $\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ as you suggest. Just some food for thought about things that seem "generally accepted".

Comment: @NoahSchweber In my view natural numbers have an order; groups have a binary operation which satisfies the group axioms; matrices have matrix addition and multiplication.  If they did not have these properties then we would call them by a different name.

Comment: @Henry OK, but that's not the view that set-theoretic implementation adopts, and that's the context of this question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the correction about the standard definition of ordered pair! My question is not about what the role of set theory should be, or how it should be approached, or similar. I simply asked whether there is a standard set-theoretic definition of matrix or array, and in that case what it is. I think it's a simple and perfectly legitimate question. From the comments I deduce that there's no standard definition, either because no proposals have been made in the literature or because there's no major agreement.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to see a good, clear answer to this question, instead of having a number of confusing comments.