# Can a Matrix be defined as a Cartesian Product $f \times g$ of two linear functions $f,g$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to think of a natural way of introducing matrices from the side of simultaneous equations

Would it be mathematically sound to define a matrix as the Cartesian product of two linear functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

For example, let:
$$f(x_1,x_2)=2x_1+x_2=b_1 $$
$$g(x_1,y_2)=8x_1-x_2=b_2$$
then $(f \times g): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined such that $$(f \times g)(x_1,x_2)=(f(x_1,x_2),g(x_1,x_2))=(b_1,b_2)$$ is known as a *matrix*

Ideas welcome :)

Comment: [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4110827/803927)

Comment: your definition has problems. how do you get a four by four matrix with your definition?

Comment: 1. That's not really a _Cartesian product_ of functions, but an _ordered pair_. But yes, a linear transformation into a Cartesian $n$-space may be viewed as an ordered $n$-tuple of linear functions. 2. A matrix (arguably a type of data structure) and a linear transformation ($n$-space-valued mapping) are not exactly the same thing. 3. IIRC, a real matrix may be viewed as a real-valued function of a pair of discrete indices taking  non-zero values at only finitely many points.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewD.Hwang for the detailed response!

Comment: @CSquared, thanks for that! Good question, definitely isn't rigorous but I like Andrew Hwang's answer here. I think a 4 x 4 matrix would be the ordered pair $(f,g,h,i)$ of linear functions $f,g,h,i: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and acts similar to the above?

Comment: @Malcolm the objects you are describing are not the same. you are describing a linear transformation by decomposing it into ordered tuples of linear transformations, which is fine, but it is not a matrix.