# About the definiton of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, education

I have a basic question about the definition of a matrix. It is usually defined as a rectangular or two-dimensional array which is OK. Could we define a matrix as co-domain of a function form $\mathbb{N}_k\times\mathbb{N}_{k'}$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{N}_k$ stands for $$\{1,\ldots,k\}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is basically the same thing.

Comment: But, why this way of definition never use in contexts?

Comment: Not the codomain but the function itself is the matrix.

Comment: @Gozal Because the precise set-theoretic definition of a matrix is usually not important. We just work with the visual representation of a matrix and keep in the back of our heads that there is a formal definition that we can use to formally justify every argument.

Comment: @BartMichels Thanks. I got that. Also, the order of a matrix if regarding it as a function  can make difficulties. However I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162576/682094)

Comment: Very often, the set of $m\times n$ real matrices is denoted by ${\bf R}^{m\times n}$. And very often, $A^B$ is interpreted as the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. So, the matrices are the functions from $\{1,2,\dots,m\}\times\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to the reals, just as you said.